# What is doing this code and how ot create test scenarios for it?

Tags: testing

Can you explain what's output and why? Also wanna know how to create test scenario for this

```
if(a<b)
    if(a<c)
        print('a')
    else
        print('c')
else
    if(a<c)
        print('b')
    else
        print('c')
```

Comment: Hmm.. this seems like homework to me

Comment: @Alex yes, it is, and?

Answer (score 0):

What gets output entirely depends on the value of your variables. If you substitute `a` `b` and `c` with numbers (lets say `1`, `2`, and `3`), your code becomes:

```
if (1<2)
    if (1<3)
        print('1')
    else
        print('3')
else
    if (1<3)
        print('2')
    else
        print('3')
```

Now let's step through this logically, starting with the first condition:

```
if (1<2)
    if (1<3)
        print('1')
    else
        print('3')
```

`1<2` evaluates to true, so we now execute the inner contents of this condition:

```
(1<3)
    print('1')
```

1 is less than 3, so we print "1". Like I said it's entirely dependent on what your variables are, so if you have anything other than `a=1` `b=2` `c=3`, this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimum of three function; given three values a, b, c, it returns the smallest value.

Your tests, then, should provide inputs and verify that the function returns the smallest:

```
assertEqual(min3(1, 4, 7), 1);
```

for example.